# Want to see only related schemas in mysql workbench

Tags: mysql-workbench

I work in a big project and I use hardly 5 schemas how can I see only 5 of them when I login, I know I can search tables and restrict to see only searched tables(But I can not search each time). I use MySQL workbench I have added image for understanding how wanted see the results I want only microservice schema to be visible whenever I login and I dont want to see test_db and world schemas

[image: sql-croped-image]

Answer (score 0):

You currently have a "powerful" mysql login,
which can see both relevant and irrelevant portions of your datastore.

Ask your SysAd / DBA to create a less powerful login for you,
which only has permission to view the relevant elements.